# How to solve a rnn attention neural network error?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

i am trying to develop a chatbot with the Dataset for chatbot

dataset in kaggle. i have used this training function with this model that should run sweeps in wandb to get the best hyperparameters.

```
def train():

    wandb.init(config=sweep_config)
    config = wandb.config


    input_shape = (64,)
    output_shape = (64,)

# Define the encoder
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    encoder_embedding = Embedding(MAX_TOKENS, 127)(encoder_inputs)
    encoder_lstm = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))(encoder_embedding)
    encoder_lstm = BatchNormalization()(encoder_lstm)

    # Define the decoder
    decoder_inputs = Input(shape=output_shape)
    decoder_embedding = Embedding(MAX_TOKENS, 127)(decoder_inputs)
    decoder_lstm = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(decoder_embedding)
    decoder_lstm = BatchNormalization()(decoder_lstm)
    decoder_lstm = Dropout(config.dropout)(decoder_lstm)

    # Apply attention mechanism
    attention = Attention()([decoder_lstm, encoder_lstm_repeated])

    # Concatenate attention output and decoder LSTM output
    decoder_concat = Concatenate()([decoder_lstm, attention])

    # Apply dense layer
    decoder_dense = Dense(MAX_TOKENS, activation='softmax',kernel_regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(config.l2))(decoder_concat)

    # Create the model
    model = tf.keras.models.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_dense)

    model.compile(optimizer=config.optimizer,loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")
    model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=10, callbacks=[WandbCallback("val_loss")])
    
    # Evaluate and log metrics
    loss = model.evaluate(val_dataset)
    wandb.log({"val_loss": loss})
```

and i get following wandb error:

```
wandb: ERROR Run u5rf3tmy errored: ValueError('Exception encountered when calling layer "attention" (type Attention).\n\nDimensions must be equal, but are 64 and 128 for \'{{node attention/MatMul}} = BatchMatMulV2[T=DT_FLOAT, adj_x=false, adj_y=true](Placeholder, Placeholder_1)\' with input shapes: [?,64,64], [?,64,1,128].\n\nCall arguments received by layer "attention" (type Attention):\n  • inputs=[\'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 64, 64), dtype=float32)\', \'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 64, 1, 128), dtype=float32)\']\n  • mask=None\n  • training=None\n  • return_attention_scores=False\n  • use_causal_mask=False')
```

what did i do wrong and how can i fix it.